# Refactoring QML and keeping components in scope

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a larger QML project that I'm trying to refactor so that some related components are in their own file. In my simplified example, what is part of **ThingManager.qml** was previously simply included in the **main.qml** file. Prior to refactoring, the scope of ids, **a**, **b**, and **c** were visible to **page.qml** since they were defined in the main file. As I tried to abstract these into a ThingManager component to reduce clutter in my **main.qml**, **page.qml** was no longer able to reference those with the familar scoping error:

> page.qml:9: ReferenceError: a is not defined

Given that I am loading pages similar to page.qml and want to execute methods within these components stored in another file, what is the recommended way to refactor something like this example such that **page.qml** can access methods in these components without them being defined in main.qml? Or is that simply not possible to do?

***main.qml:***

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQml 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window

    ThingManager { }

    Loader {
            id: page_loader
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
            page_loader.setSource("page.qml")
    }
}
```

***ThingManager.qml:***

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    Column {
            Button {
                    id: a
                    text: "A"
            }
            Button {
                    id: b
                    text: "B"
            }
            Button {
                    id: c
                    text: "C"
            }
    }
}
```

***page.qml:***

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Page {
        id: page

        Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("Execute A's method")
                a.toggle()
        }
}
```

Comment: You should add an id to `ThingManager` and define alias `a` as a property in `ThingManager.qml`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That was the combination I needed. I was trying to apply an property alias but placed the id in ThingManager.qml rather than the instantiation which caused other errors. Unfortunately, I don't have the privilege to mark your comment as the answer otherwise I would do so. I can post the updated code as the answer with attribution to your comment at least.

Comment: I added it as an answer, including a sketch of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an id to `ThingManager` and define `a` as an alias property in `ThingManager.qml` as follows:

**main.qml**:

```
...
ThingManager {id: manager }
...
```

**ThingManager.qml**:

```
Item {
    property alias a: a // makes 'a' available outside this file
    property alias b: b
    property alias c: c

    ...
}
```

**page.qml**:

```
...
manager.a.toggle ()
...
```